# IoT Malware and Botnets

Tags: security, mirai

According to Wikipedia, **A botnet is a logical collection of Internet-connected devices such as computers, smartphones or Internet of things (IoT) devices whose security have been breached and control ceded to a third party.**

So, can we say that all IoT Malware families are **botnets** as the IoT devices affected by malware are controlled by C&C (Example: Mirai) or use P2P (Example: Hajime) for further infection?

Comment: you used the word `all` ... that means 100% ... that can never be answered `yes`